# Backbone view on button not rendering

Tags: button, backbone.js

I've just started out using backbone. I want to apply a view to a button, but when I open my file in the browser there is nothing there.

Why isn't the button being rendered?

HTML:

```
   <!-- Scripts -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/backbone-min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="views/BaseButtonView.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <script type="text/template" id="button-test">
        <div id="test-buttons">
            <button class="cta-ajax">
                <p>send message</p>
                    <div class="spinner-container"></div>
            </button> 
        </div>
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

View:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var ButtonView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: $(".cta-ajax"),

        template: _.template($("#button-test").html()),

        initialize: function(){ 
            console.log("Started!");
        },

        render: function() {


            this.$el.html(this.template()); 
            console.log("rendered");
            return this; 
        }
    });

    var TView = new ButtonView();

});
```

Comment: is that all your code? I think you are missing the initialization of your view, in the code that you shared its just the declaration of your view

Comment: Well what does the initialize function do then?

Comment: you are declaring your backbone view..but you are not initializing it ..something like savebuttonView = new ButtonView()...this is actually the line that will create an instance of your view.

Comment: if you are familiar with jsfiddle i recomend you to create a fiddle for this, its much easier to help you that way.

Comment: I had done that already, but get an underscore error - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined `

Comment: that part..is not in your question, can you share all your code?

Comment: That is all my code. What am I missing?

Comment: I have updated my code and initialized it. It is still not working. The render function is not being called!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues with your code. Here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cj4zkyow/1/

**Issue 1:**

Aside from implementing the initialize function, you also need to call `render` within `initialize`. Otherwise you have to call render manually.

**Issue 2:**

Second issue is that you set the `el` attribute of your view to `.cta-ajax`, but the element does not exist. It is part of your template. The el attribute is the element that your view gets appended to. So you need to use something that exists in the DOM.

HTML:

```
// Need a element to append view to.
<div id="test"></div>

<script type="text/template" id="button-test">
    <div id="test-buttons">
        <button class="cta-ajax">
            <p>send message</p>
            <div class="spinner-container"></div>
        </button> 
    </div>
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ButtonView = Backbone.View.extend({
        // If you specify, el, it should be an element in the DOM, not in your template.
        el: $("#test"),

        template: _.template($("#button-test").html()),

        initialize: function(){ 
            // Need to call render in initialize function to render view.
            this.render();
        },

        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template()); 
            return this; 
        }
    });

    var TView = new ButtonView();

});
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. It works now. Although you are calling `render()` twice if you call it again after initializing `TView()`.

Comment: Yeah that was a typo. Should be fixed in answer and fiddle now. You don't need to do `TViewer().render()` if you call `render` in initialize.

Comment: I would recommend not to call render() method in initialize and, instead, call it in the main flow (TView.render()). It makes the code more readable (you see where the object was initialised and where it was rendered without going inside of the object). But that's just my opinion.

Comment: @Mironor That's a good point. Been a while since I used Backbone, so I took a look at some of my old production code and I also explicitly call `render()` in my views.